# How to throw error to only use one option flag when using getopts in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I have been searching but i have a question in regards to bash scripting and getopts.

I am trying to build a fool proof script using getops. What would be the best approach so when the user using the option that it will throw an error if i add more than one.

Example:

script.sh -a > this will run options a

script.sh -aaaaa > an erro should throw something that says, only 1 flag is allowed.

Comment: Set a flag when you see the option, unless the flag is already set in which case you throw the error.

Comment: In general, Stackoverflow will be kinder to you if you show that you have made an effort.  So, edit your answer and add your current code, working or not.

Comment: sorry im new to the forum...will add code and check your script below John..thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses `getopts` to parse options.  When option `a` is seen, it sets variable `a` to have the value `Yes`.  Before doing that, however, it checks to see if `a` already has a value.  If it does, it prints an error.

```
#!/bin/sh
die () {
        echo "ERROR: $*. Aborting." >&2
        exit 1
}

a=
while getopts a arg ; do case $arg in
        a)
                [ "$a" ] && die "Option a already specified"
                a=Yes
                ;;
        :)      die "${0##*/}: Must supply an argument to $OPTARG." ;;
        \?)     die "Invalid option. Abort" ;;
        esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

echo "Doing something useful now..."
```

The key part of the code is:

```
[ "$a" ] && die "Option a already specified"
```

The construct `[ "$a" ]` tests the value of `$a`.  If it is non-empty, then the test returns true and this triggers the `&&` operator to run the `die` command.  If it is empty, then `[ "$a" ]` returns false and the `die` command is *not* run.

`die` is a function: it prints a message and exits with error code 1.